# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161 resource controller

Tags: laravel-5.3

I am using following code in routes/web.php

```
Route::resource('affiliate/account', 'Affiliate\AccountController',
    [
        'pSignup'                  => 'affiliate.signup',
        'gSettings'                 => 'affiliate.settings'
    ]
);
```

Controller is in app/Http/Controllers/Affiliate/AccountController.php

I am getting following error.

NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161

Any suggestions, what is causing this error?

Comment: On which URL you are getting this error?

Comment: http://localhost/laravel53/public/affiliate.signup

Comment: Can you tell me what can be affiliate/account in above mentioned code?